# R CMD check encounters an unexpected symbol error ".Last" in an R temporary file

Tags: r, r-package

I was copying and pasting the code in section 2.9 of the [R package tutorial by Hadley Wickham and Jenny Bryan](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html). When I executed the R CMD check `check()` for the example package `foofactors`, an error occurred:

```
i Updating foofactors documentation
i Loading foofactors
-- Building ------------------------------------------------ foofactors --
Setting env vars:
* CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
* CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
* CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
√  checking for file 'D:\Guides and Tools\R\Rpackage\foofactors/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'foofactors':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory 'foofactors/man'
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
-  building 'foofactors_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'
   
-- Checking ------------------------------------------------ foofactors --
Setting env vars:
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_: FALSE
* _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_       : FALSE
* _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_      : FALSE
* NOT_CRAN                      : true
-- R CMD check -----------------------------------------------------------
   Error in source("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpoPuJln\\file78c4287d739d",  : 
     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPuJln\file78c4287d739d:1:31: unexpected symbol
   1: options(vsc.use_httpgd = TRUE).Last
```

How did this error happen? How can I probably solve it? I have no clue about the problem as

- I can only find a folder named `file78c4287d739d`, but I can't find any text file containing `options(vsc.use_httpgd = TRUE).Last`
- `vsc.use_httpgd` is an option used for vscode-r, it is confusing how this setting causes the problem as I am using Rstudio right now.

Here is some of my system info:

```
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                         
 version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)  
 os       Windows 10 x64                
 system   x86_64, mingw32               
 ui       RStudio                       
 language (EN)                          
 collate  Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
 ctype    Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
 tz       Asia/Taipei                   
 date     2021-10-08
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been answered in this [Github issue](https://github.com/r-lib/rcmdcheck/issues/170). The error happens under old versions of `rcmdcheck` when there is not a terminating newline.